# Trying to create multiple Modx resources from a form

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

I have a form that is within a table that looks similar to the below, I have a Modx snippet that runs when this is submitted that should create multiple new resources, based on the input arrays send through.

```
<table class="table responsive-table">
           <thead>

               <th>pagetitle</th>
               <th>longtitle</th>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <tr>

               <td><input type="text" name="pagetitle[]" value="" /></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="longtitle[]" value=""/></td>    
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <td><input type="text" name="pagetitle[]" value="" /></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="longtitle[]" value=""/></td>    
               </tr>
           </tbody>

       </table>
```

What is happening when the below runs is, it creates the new resources as expected however all the fields are set to "Array". and not the value of the array.

```
<?php
$allFormFields = $hook->getValues(); 


foreach ($allFormFields as $key => $value)
{
    $doc = $modx->newObject('modResource');
    $doc->set('createdby', $modx->user->get('id'));
    $doc->set('pagetitle', $value['pagetitle']);
    $doc->set('longtitle', $value['longtitle']);
    $doc->save();
}

return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print_r()` on `$allFormFields` will very likely give you something like this:

```
// dump of form values
Array (
    [pagetitle] => Array (
        [0] => 'pagetitle1'
        [1] => 'pagetitle2'
    ),
    [longtitle] => Array (
        [0] => 'longtitle1'
        [1] => 'longtitle2'
    ),
)
```

That's why you're getting 'Array' when you try to set your resource fields to `$allFormFields['pagetitle']`.

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing, but it would probably be better to construct your form like this instead:

```
<input type="text" name="resource[0][pagetitle]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="resource[0][longtitle]" value="" />    

<input type="text" name="resource[1][pagetitle]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="resource[1][longtitle]" value="" />
```

Then you can loop through the form fields for each resource like this:

```
<?php
$allFormFields = $hook->getValues();
$userId = $modx->user->get('id');

foreach ($allFormFields['resource'] as $fields) {
    $doc = $modx->newObject('modResource');
    $doc->set('createdby', $userId);
    $doc->set('pagetitle', $fields['pagetitle']);
    $doc->set('longtitle', $fields['longtitle']);
    $doc->save();
}
```

Comment: I think object's fromArray method will be useful there instead of multiple set methods.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks okyanet,

I ended up doing the below which works as I was hoping:

```
<?php
$allFormFields = $hook->getValues();

$resources = array();

foreach ($allFormFields as $field => $values) {
    if (is_array($values)) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $resources[$key][$field] = $value;
        }
    }
}



foreach ($resources as $resource) {

    if ($resource[pagetitle] == '') {
        continue;
    }
    $doc = $modx->newObject('modResource');
    $doc->fromArray($resource);
    $doc->set('createdby', $modx->user->get('id'));
    $doc->set('template', $hook->getValue('template'));
    $doc->set('parent', $hook->getValue('parent'));
    $doc->save();
}
return true;
```